# Use multiple domain to load content from main domain

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have 2 domain: domain1.com and domain2.com
my main domain is **domain1.com** and i want to load all may pages with domain2.com same as domain1.com

for example this is a news from main domain:

```
http://domain1.com/index.php?newsid=23
```

how i can show that news with this link:

```
http://domain2.com/index.php?newsid=23
```

i dont wanna use redirect or somthing like that. is there any trick with htaccess? i hope you guys understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a domain2.com alias on your domain1.com vhost config file.

Comment: Depends on your hosting configuration ? (OS, domain management system, etc). What configuration are you using?

Comment: Check this out :http://www.servwise.com/en/knowledgebase/366/How-to-create-an-Alias-on-cPanel.html